# create a hybrid cloud between aws ec2 and my local openstack instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud, openstack, hybrid

I want to create a hybrid cloud for demo purpose using the public cloud as AWS EC2 instance and the private cloud as Openstack instance which is present on my local network. Can anyone give me an idea about where to begin. If i am successful, should I be able to ping the private IP address of EC2 instance from my Openstack's instance?

I have tried a bit with OpenVPN Access Server on Openstack's instance and creating VPC and a customer gateway in AWS. Is this a right way to do it?

Comment: makes sense to me.  i'd use tinc instead of openvpn, but you know whatever tickles your pickle.

Answer (score 2):

[Tinc](http://www.tinc-vpn.org/) and will work as long as you have a public IP address on one of your VPC instances. Keep in mind that all machines need to be connected to the same Virtual Tinc network.

Same way with [openVPN](https://openvpn.net/). It will require an external public IP address.

Another way of doing is creating a Customer Gateway, a Virtual Gateway and a VPN connection in your VPC configuration on Amazon. Then you can connect your branch or office with a router to that VPN connection using IPsec. Amazon recommends all the following as a router:

[image: Supported Customer Gateways]